# Is it possible for an Eclipse plugin to make contributions to only a certain view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popup, eclipse-cdt

I have an Eclipse plugin that makes a contribution to the right click menu of the projects in the workspace.

To do that, I use the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point and the locationURI for my menu contribution is : "popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions"

The issue is that my plugin is also appearing in the Navigator View but I would like it to appear only in the C/C++ Projects View (id : org.eclipse.cdt.ui.CView)

How could I do that ?

Comment: If you can find the id of that menu you can specify it in the `popup:xxx` URI. Finding the id is tricky, I usually look at the plugin.xml of the relevant plug-ins to see if they use it.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution, the URI was popup:com.tasking.managedbuilder.cview?after=additions. I used the Yuri plugin to find the id